# Write in the app.config file how to run code on weekends and certain times only

Tags: c#, app-config

I'm writing a small application that will only run on weekends and weekdays between 6pm and 9am. I intend to do this in the app.config file. I've never worked with the app.config file and I'm looking for some direction on how I would go about implementing this task

Comment: Believe is better to do it through task scheduler

Comment: The app config isn't really for this. Why do you wish to use it?

Comment: `App.config` simply *stores settings*. It doesn't do anything. It's just a file. You'll have to either write the code to schedule and run jobs, or simply add a Scheduled Task.

Comment: I have set up code to send an auto email response. I only want it to run on certain days

Comment: http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/

Comment: `I only want it to run on certain days` you'll have to write the code to do this. Why don't you use Scheduled Tasks? The functionality is already there in the operating system

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy that would require either an always running application or a service. Task Scheduler is a safer choice, especially if there is confusion about configuration settings

Answer (score 1):

Place a  time key/value pair in your app.config. Have your code check to determine if the current time is within the time parameters in the app.config.

```
>     >     Configuration myConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Application.ExecutablePath);
>     >         myConfig.AppSettings.Settings.Add("StartTime", "1800");
>     >         myConfig.AppSettings.Settings.Add("EndTime", "0900");
>     >         myConfig.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Minimal);
```

then have your c# code convert the current time to your desired format then check if time is  greater than start time and less then end time